# CSHARP running while every X seconds but until bool is true

Tags: c#

I would like to check updates from txt file on web server. and send a messagebox when there is version mismatch, I'm using this code and it works but I want it only to connect the server every 10 minutes and check the text file.

is there any option to do that?
maybe using another way to create this loop?

I also would like to send the messagebox only once

```
bool hasDisplayed = false;
private string UpdateCheckServer()
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/update/update_version.txt");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string serverversion = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return serverversion;

}

private string UpdateCheckClient()
{
    string ClientVersion = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("update_version.txt");
    return ClientVersion;

}


private void UpdateCheckTimer()
{


    while (!hasDisplayed)
    {
        if (starter.Enabled == true && UpdateCheckServer() == UpdateCheckClient())

        {

            //Nothing here

        }

        if (starter.Enabled == true && UpdateCheckServer() != UpdateCheckClient())

        {

            MessageBox.Show("not updated");
            hasDisplayed = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a timer? Sleeping would also be an option, but a rather bad one.

Comment: The question is how do I implant timer in this code, tried several ways, timer wasn't functioning well.

Comment: I guess you need to use some scheduler to do this, something like quartz .net should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation based on timer can look like this:

```
private bool _equalVersion = true;
private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 60 * 10); //millisecond * seconds * minutes

private void StartUpdateCheckTimer()
{
    _timer.Elapsed += UpdateCheck;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void UpdateCheck(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Stop();

    _equalVersion = (UpdateCheckServer() == UpdateCheckClient());
    if (!_equalVersion)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not updated");
    }
    else
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

in this way you get a timer:

- triggered each 10 minutes,
- performing the check
- notifying the version change (and stopping) or proceeding with the subsequent iterations

then you can add some more logic like for example reset of the check, more proper notification action (separating your check routine from the GUI part) and many more.

Another approach (as pointed out by @imsmn) can be to make your implementation System.Threading.Sleep based, but I'd suggest the first option based on timer.

Answer (score -1):

After several tries and learning I managed to do that.

```
        private string UpdateCheckServer()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/update/update_version.txt");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string serverversion = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return serverversion;

    }

    private string UpdateCheckClient()
    {
        string ClientVersion = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("update_version.txt");
        return ClientVersion;

    }


    private void UpdateCheckTimer()
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer t = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();


        t.Interval = 15000; // specify interval time as you want
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        t.Start();

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Call method
    

            if (starter.Enabled == true && UpdateCheckServer() != UpdateCheckClient())

            {
                    t.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("not updated");

                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is so bad, don't do network I/O on the GUI thread, use proper `async` code.

Comment: Can you give me an example of reading network txt file so it will be easier for me to understand?